# Why groupby method gives NA values?

Tags: python, pandas-groupby

Python 3.9.6, Pandas 1.2.4

I want to find the number of patients admitted by hospital for each date. I wrote this code:

```
import pandas as pd

data_admission = data[['name_of_hospital', 'date_admission']].copy(deep=True)
data_admission = data_admission.dropna()
data_admission = data_admission.sort_values(by=['date_admission'])

data_admission['quantity_admission'] = 1
grouped = data_admission['quantity_admission'].groupby(data_admission['name_of_hospital'])
data_admission['quantity_admission'] = grouped.cumsum()

grouped = data_admission['quantity_admission'].groupby([data_admission['name_of_hospital'], data_admission['date_admission']])
result = grouped.max()
```

In the field *quantity_admission* of *result* variable, I got NAN- values, although none of the columns have empty values.
Why?

Simple example (which works great):

```
hosp1 = 'Name_1'
hosp2 = 'Name_2'

date1 = np.datetime64('2020-04-02', 'D')
date2 = np.datetime64('2020-04-01', 'D')
date3 = np.datetime64('2020-04-04', 'D')
date4 = np.datetime64('2020-04-03', 'D')

data_hosp = []
data_date = []
for date in [date2, date2, date3, date4]:
    data_hosp.append(hosp1)
    data_date.append(date)
    
    data_hosp.append(hosp2)
    if date==date2:
        data_date.append(date1)
    else:
        data_date.append(date3)
        
    
df = pd.DataFrame({'hospital':data_hosp, 'date':data_date})
df = df.sort_values(by=['date'])

df['count'] = 1
grouped = df['count'].groupby(df['hospital'])
df['count'] = grouped.cumsum()

grouped = df['count'].groupby([df['hospital'], df['date']])
df = grouped.max()
```

UPDATE:
I found out that the NAN-values are obtained in those sets of columns *name_of_hospital* and *date_admission* that were not in the original data. It's not clear why pandas adds these nonexistent combinations with NAN- values.

Comment: I'm not sure `groupby` is used correctly. You usually grab the column you want after the grouping, not before. Try `data_admission.groupby(['name_of_hospital', 'date_admission'])` etc

Comment: Could you give a sample of your data?

Comment: I think you need to explain more about the purpose of your program to understand what you intended to do with your code. You could also support us with data.

Comment: I add a sample, which which does not contain NAN values in the results.

Comment: That's indeed strange. Could you try the last `groupby` with the option `observed=True`?

Comment: @Aleksey.Stack: Can you undelete your question about `lru_cache`. I was about to post an answer.